# Python 3.4 SSL error urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-3.4

I use Arch Linux, python 3.4, openSSL 1.0.2d. When I make request to https://www.supercash.cz/ I get this error. It doesn't matter if I use requests or build in urllib there is always the same error. SSL certificate for this site seams to be OK in Chrome browser.

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 463, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 481, in _open
    '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1225, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)>
```

I tried this but it only works in python2.7
[Error - urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol , help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772847/error-urlopen-error-errno-8-ssl-c504-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protoco)

This is result of ssl test https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=supercash.cz

Comment: I was facing the same issue because I opened the proxy in PyCharm and the proxy was down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the same error as this one: [Python Requests requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14102416/407580)

You'll have to use custom `HTTPAdapter` as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14146031/407580

```
>>> import requests
>>> from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
>>> from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
>>> import ssl
>>>
>>> class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
...     def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
...         self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
...                                        maxsize=maxsize,
...                                        block=block,
...                                        ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
...
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
>>> s.get('https://www.supercash.cz')
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: doesn't work with openssl 1.0.0e-2ubuntu and python 3.2.2, site www.pca.org.

Answer (score 8):

One potential solution is described here

<s>https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3006#issuecomment-274058323</s>

https://web.archive.org/web/20160705110216/https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3006

> Using python3 and installing the combo (pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 urllib3) did the trick.

```
pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 urllib3
```