# SSL certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

Do you know about this error:

```
urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)
```

This error occurred on my server when I run my app which is written on python, but when I run this app on local computer for sending requests to that server it works without any error.
The python app sent to https request to `myhost.com/action`. and the web host is working with https. I checked ssl from [sslchecker](https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker) and it seems ssl installed succesfully. here is checker result:[image]

I don't know what I must show here to explain my problem. If you have a question about code or server settings I will try to answer as I can.

** This question isn't duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115607/python-3-4-ssl-error-urlopen-error-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol-ssl-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are ssl certificates verified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188266/how-are-ssl-certificates-verified)

Comment: what part of "certificate verify failed" is unclear?

Comment: In my case web application work normaly, I checked ss from sslchecker.com, and it gots no error

Comment: Then add details about what works and what doesn't. And whether and how each part verifies certificates when using SSL.

Comment: I am not good at ssl, but I hoped that error code means something

Comment: It means that the process described in the duplicate question failed.

Answer (score 3):

A new ssl certification checking system is added in python 3, and one way to avoid the error of not passing certification is to nullify this mechanism:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work for you because i don't know your code. But i had the same problem. With this 4 lines my code work perfect:

```
import request

#disable ssl warning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

When you connect, set the parameter of sslContext to context.